# What is meant by prototyping in Python?

Tags: python, r, prototype, julia

Articles I read about Julia discuss the two language problem and use Python or R as example. You create a program in Python but then have to call a library like numPy, which is written in C. For statistical computing, Python is slow and the library is meant to help speed things up. Hence the two language problem.

This is described as prototyping in Python (or R if it is being used in the example). What do they mean by prototyping?

Here are some examples:

(start of 2nd paragraph) https://www.mapr.com/blog/julia-fresh-approach-numerical-computing-and-data-science

(3rd paragraph) https://sinews.siam.org/DetailsPage/tabid/607/ArticleID/744/Julia-A-Fast-Language-for-Numerical-Computing.aspx

Comment: I think that these types of articles are usually arguing that it's really quick to write something in python because the language is so expressive and has such a powerful standard library.  This initial code is the "prototype", but then the authors of these articles go on to talk about how python isn't suitable for large projects because it's slow and doesn't have type-safety, etc. etc. (an assertion that I disagree with completely).  So then you need to rebuild the whole thing in a language that is harder to use but "more suitable for big projects".  Again, I generally disagree with this.

Comment: @mgilson Could you expand on why you disagree? For example, what would you use to speed up a Monte Carlo calculation or something like that that is inherently sequential?

Comment: I guess that they are saying that implementing  an algorithm (the *prototype*) that works is very easy in R or Python, but then you have to deal to the fact that with a larger input that algorithm may be too slow to be used. I guess that responds to your answer. I hope that the discussion doesn't move to a "this language against that language" religion war, which is totally off topic in SO.

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders -- I said that I _generally_ disagree.  The one corner where I _might_ agree is in algorithms development or true High Performance Computing.  Even there, you can frequently do the tricky high-level book-keeping in a language like python and just farm out the performance critical parts to a more performant language...

Comment: @nicola: I still don't know why the use of the word "prototype". They are creating a program. Not a prototype. Why do you think an algorithm is a prototype? That algorithm becomes production code eventually. So no - it isn't a prototype. It is part of a program.

Comment: Is your question about the choose of a word? I can't respond for the authors. I guess that they refer to the fact that sometimes you come up with a "quick and dirt" solution that works, but that cannot go in production or constitute the base of a mature software. They call this solution "prototype". That's how I intend those sentences. I may be wrong of course. However, I don't think is any useful to discuss the use of that word, since the sense of their reasoning is pretty clear.

Comment: Yes - the use of the word. I'm not interpreting this as quick and dirty. That wouldn't really make any sense. This is how Python and R programmers do it for their production code, which by definition is not quick and dirty.

Comment: Python and R programmers do what for their production code? They put in production the first thing they come up with?

Comment: You really think everyone starts production code with by prototyping first?

Comment: I don't of course. Why are you asking? All they are saying is that some programs in R or Python don't scale well, that's it. And if you want them to scale, you have to use another language, and they call the first program "prototype". That's it. You don't like the word? I guess the concept they are telling is pretty clear.

Comment: (don't know if it is needed, but I don't support any of their ideas; I'm just describing what they are saying)

Comment: @nicola: 2nd to last post above was a good description of it.

Comment: This [book](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Pragmatic_Programmer.html?id=5wBQEp6ruIAC&redir_esc=y) describes the meaning - and the use - of "prototyping" quite clearly.

Comment: No matter what language you use, it is common to prototype a solution, without worrying about performance/scalability too much (remember the Donald Knuth quote "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"), see what parts really are performance/scalability bottlenecks, and then work on improving those parts.  The two-language problem occurs when the language you used is not fast enough for improving those parts that really are the bottleneck, so you need to write code in another language, often C or C++ and call out to it. That can be difficult for a scientist, just trying to get results.

Comment: That is the advantage of Julia over most dynamic languages.  You can see that most all of the Julia "standard library" is actually written natively in Julia, only a few math libraries such as BLAS (Linear Algebra), FFTW (Fast Fourier Transform), mpfr (multiple precision floating-point routines) are in C or Fortran).  Like Python, Julia is very expressive and fast to "prototype" a working solution, but unlike Python, with Julia it is also easy to iteratively refine the "prototype" code into scalable production ready code. (Note: we've been doing exactly that for the last year where I work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they mean is that a data analyst who knows how to program e.g. Python will often quickly write code which gives the correct answer for small to medium data sets.  Then, once the idea is validated, for various reasons the code has to be rewritten, sometimes in an entirely different language like C++ (second language problem).

Python has reasonably good bindings to C and C++ and to a lesser extent R and others.  But it does get confusing to program this way (if you are writing in both, not using mature libraries written in C from Python).  It's harder to debug.

NumPy and SciPy help because they let you express numeric data transformations using Python code but the implementations are highly optimized in C and Fortran.  But what if your algorithm doesn't have an obvious translation to vector or matrix operations?  It may take quite some effort (and revalidation) to produce a program which is fast on large data sets.

Some people claim that e.g. Julia lets you write code quickly but doesn't make it so easy to write code that is slow.

Comment: "NumPy and SciPy help because they let you express numeric data transformations using Python code but the implementations are highly optimized in C and Fortran." That part is what I'm referring to as the two language problem and where "prototype" comes up.  I don't really see why it is a problem or why it is a prototype. Many languages call libraries (C or not). I'm just not sure why Julia articles calls this prototyping when all other languages do not. Yet it is the same thing.

Comment: "...and to a lesser extent R..." I think that C-R binding is excellent and is very easy to extend R with C code.

Comment: @nicola: What I wrote there is that Python has bindings to C, and Python has lesser bindings to R.  Not that R has lesser bindings to C.

Comment: @4thSpace, that's not really what they are generally referring to by prototyping.  The two language problem is not when you call out to a library written in some other language, the problem is when there is no library that does just what you need, and you need to write C, C++, or Fortran code *yourself* in order to get the performance/scalability needed for critical sections of your code, when trying to make it production ready.